# "ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore" Despite PyQt5 being imported

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've been going through this package of python scripts:

https://github.com/werdeil/clementine-last-export

To convert from pyqt4 to pyqt5 as pyqt4 is no longer supported on my OS.

I did both a manual conversion and a conversion using the following script:

https://github.com/rferrazz/pyqt4topyqt5

Both the script and the conversion from pyqt4->pyqt5 seem straight-forward but once I am done converting the scripts I still get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 374, in <module>
    main()
  File "gui.py", line 355, in main
    cleg = ClemLastExportGui()
  File "gui.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.load_config()
  File "gui.py", line 350, in load_config
    self.config = pickle.load(open(self.configfile))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1139, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore
```

despite the fact that no refrences to pyqt4 are even active in the source:

```
~/projects/clementine-last-export $ grep -i pyqt4 -r *
README.txt:pyqt4 stopped being supported by most Linux Operating Systems
```

I looked through the libraries on my system and pyqt4 is entirely gone, so that doesn't seem likely to be the cause.

Could someone take a look at my code here:

https://github.com/davidsmind/clementine-last-export

Or point me in the right direction if it is a system issue?

Comment: Have you followed the exception? It seems that pickle tries to load the PyQt4 module , so there is propably a reference to PyQt4 in the config file. Try to remove/reset that config file and see if it makes a difference

Comment: This was the solution!


/home/USER/.clementine_last_export/config.pkl